# Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: boxgrinder-noarch

Tags: fedora, yum

I am trying to run `yum update` on my machine and I get this error.

```
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: boxgrinder-noarch. Please verify its path and try again
```

Any idea what is wrong?

I use `Fedora 15`

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with the standard fedora repository.  There is a big thread on fedoraforum.org where the consensuses seems to be that it is network-related, i.e. yum can't contact hosts in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files.

Comment: Yes, if there is any network issue, yum cannot contact any repo. But for me, it was only this particular repo file (boxgrinder) that was failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this error by removing the `boxgrinder repos`

I removed these files

```
boxgrinder-nightly.repo   boxgrinder-noarch.repo   boxgrinder-x86_64.repo
```

from `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory.

Comment: For people who don't use boxgrinder, but have this problem anyway, look at the other answers. It's about https in the repo file, which should be replaced with http.

Comment: Ouch. It's possible this solved some problem in 2013, but in 2017 and on, please don't switch to http for Fedora repositories. Our tooling properly handles https.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
perl -i -ape 's/https:/http:/g' *.repo
```

worked for me.

Comment: cd /etc/yum.repos.d/;  perl -i -ape 's/https:/http:/g' *.repo  # two commands

Comment: Why is this not an answer? It solves the problem, replacing https with http, because the repos can be accessed via http only it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem in Fedora 14.

When I changed the *.repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d, it works.

**"Change all 'https' to 'http' in each *.repo file"**
such as:

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
baseurl=ftp://ftp.cru.fr/pub/linux/fedora/releases/11/Everything/x86_64/os/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearchthe
```

change is like this

```
"mirrorlist=https:"--->"mirrorlist=*http:*"
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually an answer to the Q. If you solved the problem can you please reword otherwise delete it as it isn't actually an answer to the Q. As you're new see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is actually a helpful answer for me, trying to update a Fedora 15 installation.

Comment: Ouch. It's possible this solved some problem in 2013, but in 2017 and on, please don't switch to http for Fedora repositories. (And that shouldn't have been a problem in 2015, either.) Our tooling properly handles https.

Answer (score 3):

> find out the repo which is causing a problem in your case it is
>   box-grinder, remove the repo or fix it.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

mv /etc/yum.repos.d/box-grinder.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/box-grinder.repo.disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

## **[ percona ]**

**Attempting to get the percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm**

---

**The issue I had:**

`http://repo.percona.com/release/6.6/RPMS/noarch/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"`

`Trying other mirror.`

`Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: percona-release-noarch. Please verify its path and try again`

**What I did to fix the issue:**

1. `sed -i 's/$releasever/5/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/percona-release.repo`

*You won't see a response.*

2. `yum clean all`
3. `yum update`

*This should solve your problem*

What this does? `sed` overwrites whatever the percona-release.repo file says with `s/$releasever/5/g` incase the `yum clean all` doesn't catch it or some other error occurs.

[yum](/questions/tagged/yum) [repo](/questions/tagged/repo) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) [percona](/questions/tagged/percona) [fedora](/questions/tagged/fedora)